# <ContentControl>Content</ContentControl> vs. <ContentControl Content="Content"/>

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml, contentcontrol

Given the following two options:

```
<ContentControl>Content</ContentControl>
```

vs.

```
<ContentControl Content="Content"/>
```

1. Any performance differences?
2. What would you say is more readable?
3. Conclusion?

I'm affraid this question might sound somehow babyish, but how will I know if I won't ask, so I decided to shoot it.
Comment me if I chose the wrong decision ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a personal preference, I vote for

```
<ContentControl Content="Content"/>
```

but only because I find it more readable. AFAIK there is no performance impact by choosing one or the other, but I haven't done any testing to substantiate that...

Answer (score 7):

The two are identical, in terms of what is generated.  The performance will be identical.

The first option, however, let's you put something that isn't directly generated via a simple text string or a markup extension, such as:

```
<ContentControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Content" />
    <Image Source="SomeImage.png" />
  </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

If, however, you're only putting in a single text string, I find the second more readable.

Comment: Weird, I would just like to state this would be the better answer as it is the correct reason!

Comment: Yeah, well, it's the more complete reason, at least.